# akka-cluster: unable to get rid of actors from scaled down node

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I face an issue using akka cluster.

System setup: 2 nodes, each having 2 instances of a worker actor. All these actors(4 in total) are tracked by a singleton actor in the application.

Issue is that when one of the node is scaled down, singleton actor still keeps having references to actors in downed node.

I am not able to get to root of the cause.

I am not sure what part in akka cluster takes care of such scenarios, and where to look for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Just because an actor goes away (because it is stopped, it fails, its node goes away, other) doesn't mean that `ActorRef`s are deleted or anything like that. That's not really even possible with the way that `ActorRef`s work: they are just ordinary objects that can be passed around/copied/etc.

You are have a few options:

1. An actor can [register to receive a message](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-lifecycle.html#watching-actors) when an actor is terminated via `watch` or `watchWith`. (As an actor you can be sent messages, unlike an ordinary object like an `ActorRef`.)
2. You could listen for cluster member changes in a similar way.
3. Rather than building your own singleton to keep track of actors, you could use the [built-in `Receptionist`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-discovery.html#receptionist) which does this kind of actor watching/cluster watching automatically.
4. Fundamentally, in a system like you are describing, message senders do need to be resilient. For example, if one of these worker actors ends up behind a network partition it's not going to be able to respond or deregister itself. There has to be some kind of backup plan as well as the above.

EDIT 1/19/24: As an example of #4 you'll note that none of the native cluster features (clustered receptionist, singleton, sharding, sharded daemon are the ones that come to immediate mind) have you keep a direct reference to a clustered Actor. You are almost always working with a "proxy" on your local node and that proxy actor does the work of tracking liveness and reachability. That's one of the reasons I suggested using the builtin Receptionist.